# Passing variable from .htaccess to PHP page

Tags: php, .htaccess, variables

I've tried everything, but I can't succeed in echoing a variable set in .htaccess. I have this

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /f3/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /f3/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

SetEnv HTTP_SITEDATA_PATH prova
```

and I try to:

```
$d = apache_getenv('HTTP_SITEDATA_PATH');
echo $d;
```

Can anyone help me?
Is a new argument for me, so ask me anything necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can access `HTTP_SITEDATA_PATH` like this: `$_SERVER['HTTP_SITEDATA_PATH']` :

```
$d = $_SERVER['HTTP_SITEDATA_PATH'];
echo $d; // output: prova
```

Comment: I already tried it. Also $_ENV instead $_SERVER, or getenv instead apache_getenv. At the moment doesn't works.

Comment: Make sure that your web server has set the `AllowOverride` option to the correct value in the configuration file in order for the `SetEnv` to be actually parsed. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Comment: Also make sure that the apache server has `mod_env` loaded.

Comment: This is the content of my apache2.conf:
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride all
            Require all denied
    </Directory>

Comment: How do I check mod_env and eventually enable it, definetely?

Comment: Look in apache2.conf for `LoadModule` directives

Comment: I didn't found "LoadModule". Is something else that I must find?

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: Xubuntu operating system

Comment: Run: sudo a2enmod env . And then: sudo service apache2 restart . That should load `mod_env`

Comment: Try and put the `SetEnv` statement inside apache2.conf just below the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` definition.

Comment: Ok, but I must continue later. I'll write here updates. Thanks.

Comment: DOCUMENT_ROOT is not present in that file.
I added the SetEnv at the end, but doesn't work.

Comment: Where have you set the `DOCUMENT_ROOT`?

Comment: ... I don't know that. I'm a bit new in apache.